# Set input value in custom search module

Tags: 7, forms

I'm using [custom search module](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) in my site. What I want to do is set a value for the input (text box) in the username and password field.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) is your friend. Take a look in the [Form API Quickstart Guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826), how to change a form for your needs.

Comment: I just stumbled over http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode53.